# Secure Connection Failed for every web page?

Tags: help

Kinda new to this. Don't expect too much technical knowledge. Used TOR on home PC for a while, installed it on laptop yesterday and it was working fine. Today I launch it and nothing. Secure Connection Failed. I've tried restarting, reinstalling, etc.

Comment: Can you post your log file, please? Without that we hardly can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCDD.jpg

I even disabled Kaspersky and it wouldn't work so can't explain it, but finally after 3 days it's working!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Patch g for Kaspersky is the problem
https://support.kaspersky.com/13617#block0