# For the past 5 days when I click on "Test for Network Setttings" all I get is "Secure Connection Failed". This is the first time this has happened.

Tags: help

Secure Connection Failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Learn more…

I have been using TOR for over a year and this is the first time this has happened. I have check my clock and the setting seem accurate to me. I am not tech savvy. I have another computer hooked up to the same router and I'm able to connect with that computer. Any help would be appreciated. I see posts with log file and I don't even know how to find a log file.

---

Comment: This looks like a problem with the website you are visiting. Does this happen for all websites? e.g. https://check.torproject.org? If so, it's probably something like your anti-virus spying on your Tor usage to report it back to the company.

Comment: Yes it happens for all websites, even check.torproject.org . I am using Kaspersky Internet Security. I have had Kaspersky for the past two years and renew each year. No problems until about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Sounds like that's a common issue, you need to tell kaspersky not to intercept encrypted comms for tor browser.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Do you know how I would do that ?

Comment: Maybe check out https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16720/secure-connection-failed-for-every-web-page seems like this is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure Connection Failed for every web page?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16720/secure-connection-failed-for-every-web-page)

Answer (score 1):

For me - Solved!

If you use Kaspersky Antivirus:

1) You can add firefox.exe from "Tor\Browser" path as a trust software
2) Kaspersky Options - Network Parametres - choose "Do not verify secured connections"

It should work.

Comment: I use Kaspersky Internet Security. I can not find under "Options" Network Parametres. Any suggestions?